# If NSString is class and it is passed by reference then why is this output?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nsstring, structure

```
var objectiveCString : NSString? = "objectiveCString"

var copiedObjectiveCString : NSString = objectiveCString!;

copiedObjectiveCString = "changedobjectiveCString"

print(copiedObjectiveCString);

print(objectiveCString!)
```

And output is

```
changedobjectiveCString
objectiveCString
```

Output should be

```
changedobjectiveCString
changedobjectiveCString
```

Because NSString is class type object and both string are now pointing to same location and value of one string is changed at the location then other string should also changed.

Comment: The behavior in Swift is exactly the same.

Comment: @vadian I thought it must be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes , even I didn't find it , please remove the tag or just let us know the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks vadian , I got the point.